# connecting dots with ggplot according to two factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to connect specific dots in a graph belonging to two separate but interacting factors, here is my sample dataframe:

```
# Number of participants, sessions, and session epochs
n_participants <- 5
n_sessions <- 7
n_session_epochs <- 4

# Create the initial data frame
participant_ids <- paste0("ID-", 1:n_participants)
sessions <- 1:n_sessions
session_epochs <- 1:n_session_epochs

# Create a data frame with all combinations of participants, sessions, and session epochs
df <- expand.grid(Participant = participant_ids, 
                  Session = sessions, 
                  Session_Epoch = session_epochs)

# Add F_response with random values
set.seed(123)  # For reproducible results
df$F_response <- sample(1:4, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)

# Function to generate increasing accuracy values
generate_accuracy <- function() {
  start_value <- runif(1, 0, 0.25)
  end_value <- 1
  seq(from = start_value, to = end_value, length.out = n_sessions * n_session_epochs)
}

# Apply the function to each participant and reshape the data
accuracy_values <- replicate(n_participants, generate_accuracy())
df$Accuracy <- as.vector(t(accuracy_values))

# Arrange the data frame by Participant, Session, and Session_Epoch
df <- df %>% arrange(Participant, Session, Session_Epoch)
```

I want to plot on the x axis accuracy and on the y axis the F_response, then I want to link sessions of each participant to each other, see my code below:

```
(a = df %>%
    filter(Session_Epoch == 1) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Accuracy, y = F_response)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(Session), shape = as.factor(Participant)), size=3) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
    geom_path(aes(group = interaction(as.factor(Participant), as.factor(Session)))) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 15)))
```

Basically I would like to link up with geom_path the symbols of the same color, following the order of Session number however my code doesn't do that (see screenshot) and R says that `Each group consists of only one observation.` what am I doing wrong?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Realised that I was over-complicating it, correct code is the following:

```
(a = df %>%
    filter(Session_Epoch == 1) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Accuracy, y = F_response)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(Session), shape = as.factor(Participant)), size=3) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
    geom_path(aes(group = as.factor(Participant))) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 15)))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).